# Laravel Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, hosting

I will deploy my Laravel application using AWS Elastic Beanstalk...
I was wondering if I should change my APP_URL to my custom domain name?
Or should I leave it unaltered?
Or should it be set to the domain on Elastic Beanstalk (which I think is most likely).

I have seen tutorials where the APP_URL was not changed in the .env file but I do not think this would work in my case considering that my application sends notification messages with a link to the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`APP_URL` should be the final domain you will use, that variable is referenced by the default email notifications, console commands, and a lot of external packages.

Try to search for APP_URL and app.url in your Laravel Project:

[image]

[image]